# Implementation the basic authenication in WCF using webHttpBinding

Tags: wcf, authentication, iis

I'm going to implement basic authentication in WCF. I'm very new in all this stuff and my program is based on this series of articles http://leastprivilege.com/2008/01/11/http-basic-authentication-against-non-windows-accounts-in-iisasp-net-part-0-intro/ I do use webHttpBinding and HTTPS is on.

So the main idea is implementation of IHttpModule in this way:

1. When user requests some resource a module checks if Authorization header is present.
2. In case of Authorization is present, the module extracts the header's value, decodes and checks login and pass
3. In the other case the module sends a response with 401 code and a header  "WWW-Authenticate".

Here is my implementation of the module:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Management;
using System.Text;

namespace MyProj_A
{
    public class MyHTTPModule : IHttpModule
    {

        void IHttpModule.Dispose()
        {
        }

        void IHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication context)
        {
            context.BeginRequest += Context_BeginRequest;
            context.AuthenticateRequest += OnEnter;
            context.EndRequest += OnLeave;
        }


        private void Context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
            context.Response.Write("BeginRequest");
        }

        void OnEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
            if (IsHeaderPresent())
            {
                if (!AuthenticateUser())
                {
                    DenyAccess();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // if anonymous requests are not allowed - end the request
                DenyAccess();
            }
        }

        bool IsHeaderPresent()
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Authorization"] != null;
        }

        bool AuthenticateUser()
        {
            string username = "", password = "";
            string authHeader = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
            if (authHeader != null && authHeader.StartsWith("Basic"))
            {
                // extract credentials from header
                string[] credentials = ExtractCredentials(authHeader);
                username = credentials[0];
                password = credentials[1];
                if (username.CompareTo("tikskit") == 0 && password.CompareTo("") == 0)
                {
                    return true;
                } else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }


        private static void DenyAccess()
        {
            HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;

            context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
            context.Response.End();
        }

        void OnLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // check if module is enabled
            if (HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode == 401)
            {
                SendAuthenticationHeader();
            }
        }

        private void SendAuthenticationHeader()
        {
            HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;

            context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
            context.Response.AddHeader(
                "WWW-Authenticate",
                "Basic realm=\"yo-ho-ho\""
                );

        }
    }

}
```

I publish it under IIS 7.5 on remote computer and connect to it with remote debugger from my Visual Studio. I set breakpoints at Context_BeginRequest, OnEnter and OnLeave.

Then I access to my WCF from a browser using URL and here is what happens:

1. After I inputted an URL and pressed the Enter Context_BeginRequest is fired
2. In VS I can see that the Authorization header isn't present
3. OnEnter is fired and eventually it assigns 401 code to the response
4. OnLeave is executed as well and it sets WWW-Authenticate to the response header
5. In the browser the standart login dialog is shown
6. I input the user name and password and press OK
7. Now Context_BeginRequest is fired again and I can see that Authorization header is present and consists a value like "Basic ", which is right
8. OnEnter isn't executed at all this time
9. OnLeave is fired but a value of HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode is 401 by some reason

Here is my Web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
  </system.web>


  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>

      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webBehavior">
          <webHttp automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>

       <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Default" >
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="false"/>
          <serviceAuthenticationManager authenticationSchemes="Basic"/>
          <serviceCredentials>
          </serviceCredentials>

        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>

    </behaviors>

    <bindings>      
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="MyBinding">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Basic"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />

    <services>
      <service name="MyProj_A.Service1">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="MyProj_A.IService1"
                  behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior"/>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <diagnostics>
      <endToEndTracing activityTracing="false" messageFlowTracing="true" propagateActivity="true"></endToEndTracing>
    </diagnostics>
  </system.serviceModel>

  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="MyHTTPModule"
        type="MyProj_A.MyHTTPModule,MyProj-A"/>
    </modules>

    <directoryBrowse enabled="false"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

So my questions are
1. Why OnEnter isn't fired second time, in 8, and how is 401 assigned in an item 9?
2. How to work around this behaviour, I mean do I need to move all the authentication processing from AuthenticateRequest (OnLeave) to BeginRequest (Context_BeginRequest) for example? Or maybe there is a better place for such processing?

Thanks!

Comment: [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.authenticaterequest.aspx) is said that AuthenticateRequest occurs when the user is already authenticated. Which makes me think that authentication is disabled in my service at all (or anonymous access is enabled). I checked IIS authentication settings for Basic Authentication is the only enabled. I also added <authentication mode="Basic"/> to system.web expecting that OnEnter will not occur. But it didn't helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case is closed

I've forgotten to refer to binding configuration in endpoint configuration:

```
<endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding"
  contract="MyProj_A.IService1" 
  behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior" 
  **bindingConfiguration="MyBinding"**/>
```